# htaccess 301 wanted experts in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Question how do i rewrite

http://www.mywebsite.nl/support/department/index.php?/Ontruimingsvonnis/Knowledgebase/List/

to

http://www.mywebsite.nl/support/knowlegdebase/list

i have tried different ways to solve it but sofar no luck. Me and htaccess just aint friends. 
Who will be able to help me out with this is need a 301 redirect for this one?

Could it also be that the index.php? would give a problem here?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

My Memory is a little hazy on this (its been a couple of years since i had to do this) but i believe mrewrite is what you need to use.

After a little digging, i found the page that might be helpful

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite